# Can I get an answer from one logic question?

Tags: modifiers

Although only half of a dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’? Or only when an entire dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’?

Comment: The question is not what you can call it. You can call it whatever you like. The question is whether someone will be able to identify it if the other half of the dish is a different colour. And, either way, it's likely to be confusing. So rather describe it properly.

Comment: It depends what the other available dishes are like. If none of them have red colouring, people will know which you are referring to, but you could qualify it by saying *reddish*. "Pass me the reddish dish please" ;)

Comment: @Ronald Sole how to describe it properly?

Comment: @Weather Vane in a general context red dish means the entire dish is red?

Comment: In a general context, I would assume someone meant the entire dish. But if I looked at the dishes and saw that one of them was only half red, I would know which one was meant. That is not a matter of English.

Comment: @Weather Vane you’re welcome

Comment: @user28482 Did you mix up "Thank you" and "You are welcome"?

Comment: @Eddie Kal♦ Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Although only half of a dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’? Or only when an entire dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’?**

This is a very badly phrased question and to this question the answer is yes, **If you name something you can call it what you want**. You can name your dog "Fire" but if you lost your dog and walked around the streets shouting Fire! Fire! other people would think you meant something other than come here Doggie! Therefore you need to be explicit. **Do you want to describe something, name something or give something a descriptive name.**

---

Therefore **I will rephrase your question as**

**Although only half of a dish is red, can it be described as a ‘red dish’? Or only when an entire dish is red, can it be described as a ‘red dish’?**

I would suggest only when the majority of the dish is red can it be described as "Red". If you wish to reference this try looking for "Chinese Blue Vases" **You will find that where the pottery is blue and white it is described as blue and white** even when it is two thirds blue with a white pattern. There are some Blue Chinese vases that are actually all blue and they are called "Blue vases".

In contrast "**Blue Cheese**" (which is the **name** of a type of Cheese) **does not have much blue colouring.**